# replaceAll regex to remove last - from the output

Tags: regex

I was able to achieve some of the output but not the right one. I am using replace all regex and below is the sample code.

```
final String label = "abcs-xyzed-abc-nyd-request-xyxpt--1-cnaq9";
System.out.println(label.replaceAll(
   "([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)", "$3"));
```

i want this output:

```
abc-nyd-request-xyxpt
```

but getting:

```
abc-nyd-request-xyxpt-
```

here is the code https://ideone.com/UKnepg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `.replaceFirst` solution:

```
String label = "abcs-xyzed-abc-nyd-request-xyxpt--1-cnaq9";
label.replaceFirst("(?:[^-]*-){2}(.+?)(?:--1)?-[^-]+$", "$1");
//=> "abc-nyd-request-xyxpt"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jg0GR/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:[^-]+-){2}`: Match 2 repetitions of non-hyphenated string followed by a hyphen
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any characters and capture in group #1
- `(?:--1)?`: Match optional `--1`
- `-`: Match a `-`
- `[^-]+`: Match a non-hyphenated string
- `$`: End

Comment: since using replaceAll in my code, I would skip replaceFirst. Thanks for your response

Comment: When you need single replacement `replaceFirst` is the way to go and `replaceAll` is a waste full call.

Comment: Hi @anubhava  sometimes the  ```String label = "abcs-xyzed-abc-nyd-request-xyxpt--1-cnaq9"``` or String label = ```"abcs-xyzed-abc-nyd-request-xyxpt-cnaq9" ```  string label with or without ```--1```  can i still get the group ```abc-nyd-request-xyxpt``` using above expression

Comment: @rishi: Check my updated answer now and the new demo

Comment: thanks @anubhava,indeed. i accepted it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for your example case

```
([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+[^-])-+([^-]+)-([^-]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/VNtryN/1

We don't want to capture any trailing `-` while allowing the trailing dashes to have more than a single one which makes it match the double `--`.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following regex. This is going to create 1 capturing group which can be used in replacement. Do replacement like: `$1`in your function.

```
^(?:.*?-){2}([^-]*(?:-[^-]*){3})--.*
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/P6LnQN/1) for above regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^(?:.*?-){2}          ##Matching from starting of value in a non-capturing group where using lazy match to match very near occurrence of - and matching 2 occurrences of it.
([^-]*(?:-[^-]*){3})  ##Creating 1st and only capturing group and matching everything before - followed by - followed by everything just before - and this combination 3 times to get required output.
--.*                  ##Matching -- to all values till last.
```